# Algorithm that selects specific combinations of values in a matrix

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, combinations

Suppose I have a matrix with m rows and n columns with each cell containing an integer. The columns represent data from individual subjects and the rows represent repeated measurements from each subject.

For each column, I want to select one (and only one) of the m rows and then calculate the average of all the selected cells and I want to do this such that I can have all the possible combinations of selecting 1 row out of the m rows for each of the n columns.

For example for a matrix with 3 rows and 4 columns one selection would be (marked in bold):

**8** 7 **5** **4**

6 **8** 7 5

6 8 9 7

another one would be

8 7 5 **4**

**6** **8** 7 5

6 8 **9** 7

So I am struggling with an algorithm (I am working in R studio) that gives me all the possible 'combinations' that I have described.

Could anyone give me any tips on how to approach this?

Thanks a lot!

Regards,

Bart

Comment: Could you further explain the selection criteria? Why was 8, 5, and 4 selected and not the others?

Comment: seems like the function `combn()` might be helpful for you

Comment: Those were just two random examples. The selection criteria are that for each of the columns I want to select one of the rows (it can be any row). So 1 'selection' consists of 10 cells, one from each column, with each cell coming from any of the rows (of that column).

Comment: As @keegan suggested, `combn(seq_len(ncol(m1)), 3)` gets the row index

Comment: Keegan, the combn() function is not the same thing because it would just select n cells out of the mxn cells whereas per selection of n cells I only want one cell from each column.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to combine the 3 elements of your 4 columns with each other you will have 3^4 = 81 combinations. You can use the command expand.grid like this:

```
dt = data.frame(x1 = c(8,6,6),
                x2 = c(7,8,8),
                x3 = c(5,7,9),
                x4 = c(4,5,7))

dt2 = expand.grid(dt$x1, dt$x2, dt$x3, dt$x4)

dt2$MEAN = apply(dt2, 1, mean)
```